# Qt/C++ Serialize generic object into QSettings

Tags: c++, qt, templates, qsettings, qvariant

I have several occurences in my application where I want to save a compound object into QSettings:

```
template <typename T>
class AwsProperty
{
public:
    AwsProperty(T value, quint64 timestamp){
        m_data = value;
        m_timestamp = timestamp;
    }
    AwsProperty(){}
    T value(){return m_data;}
    void update(T value,quint64 timestamp){m_data = value; m_timestamp = timestamp;}
    quint64 timestamp(){return m_timestamp;}

    void toQDataStream(QDataStream &dstream){dstream << m_data << m_timestamp;}
    void fromQDataStream(QDataStream &dstream){dstream >> m_data >> m_timestamp;}
private:
    quint64 m_timestamp;
    T m_data;
};

typedef AwsProperty<qint32> AwsPropertyInt32;
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(AwsPropertyInt32)
typedef AwsProperty<quint32> AwsPropertyUint32;
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(AwsPropertyUint32)
typedef AwsProperty<bool> AwsPropertyBool;
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(AwsPropertyBool)
```

the cpp looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& out, const AwsProperty<T>& classObj){
{
    classObj.toQDataStream(out);
    return out;
}
template <typename T>
QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream& in, const AwsProperty<T>& classObj){
    classObj.fromQDataStream(in);
    return in;
}
```

I registered them in my main:

```
  qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<AwsPropertyInt32>("AwsPropertyInt32");
    qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<AwsPropertyUint32>("AwsPropertyUint32");
    qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<AwsPropertyBool>("AwsPropertyBool");
```

The error I am getting is:

```
/opt/XXXXXXXXXX/0.9.99/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-XXXXXX-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/QtCore/qmetatype.h:810: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘QDataStream’ and ‘const AwsProperty<int>’)
         stream << *static_cast<const T*>(t);
         ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Also why is the streaming operator not defined for `QDataStream` and `QString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register the operators to the metatype system using [`qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators) before instantiating `QSettings`.

Also, the constness of the operators and the `fromQDataStream` and `toQDataStream` methods is slightly wrong (see the link for the exact prototype that is needed).

**EDIT:**

This code works for me: Note that I changed the constness of some methods and move the operators to the header file since they are templates.

**awsproperty.h**

```
#include <QDataStream>

template <typename T>
class AwsProperty
{
public:
    AwsProperty(T value, quint64 timestamp){
        m_data = value;
        m_timestamp = timestamp;
    }
    AwsProperty(){}
    T value(){return m_data;}
    void update(T value,quint64 timestamp){m_data = value; m_timestamp = timestamp;}
    quint64 timestamp(){return m_timestamp;}

    void toQDataStream(QDataStream &dstream) const {dstream << m_data << m_timestamp;}
    void fromQDataStream(QDataStream &dstream){dstream >> m_data >> m_timestamp;}
private:
    quint64 m_timestamp;
    T m_data;
};

template <typename T>
QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& out, const AwsProperty<T>& classObj) {
    classObj.toQDataStream(out);
    return out;
}

template <typename T>
QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream& in, AwsProperty<T>& classObj) {
    classObj.fromQDataStream(in);
    return in;
}

typedef AwsProperty<qint32> AwsPropertyInt32;
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(AwsPropertyInt32)
typedef AwsProperty<quint32> AwsPropertyUint32;
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(AwsPropertyUint32)
typedef AwsProperty<bool> AwsPropertyBool;
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(AwsPropertyBool)
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "awsproperty.h"
#include <QSettings>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<AwsPropertyInt32>("AwsPropertyInt32");
    qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<AwsPropertyUint32>("AwsPropertyUint32");
    qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<AwsPropertyBool>("AwsPropertyBool");
    QSettings set("/tmp/testsettings.conf");

    AwsPropertyInt32 a{-2, 100};
    set.setValue("property", QVariant::fromValue(a));
    auto val = set.value("property").value<AwsPropertyInt32>();
    qDebug() << val.value() << " " << val.timestamp();
}
```

Comment: I corrected them both in my question but the error remains.

Comment: Are your operators defined only in the cpp file? Templates must go in the header file.